# <UITextFieldDelegate> in derived class from UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

Giving the following derived class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NumberPadViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImage *numberPadDoneImageNormal;
    UIImage *numberPadDoneImageHighlighted;
    UIButton *numberPadDoneButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *numberPadDoneImageNormal;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *numberPadDoneImageHighlighted;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *numberPadDoneButton;

- (IBAction)numberPadDoneButton:(id)sender;

@end
```

used in this class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NumberPadViewController.h"

@interface eatAddViewController : NumberPadViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UITextField *textAmount, *textTips;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segAddType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textAmount;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textDateTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textExpenseType;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textTips;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textTotalAmount;

@end
```

using "UITextFieldDelegate" give the following error:

```
2013-01-04 22:54:32.916 ExpenseAccountTracking[39423:c07] -[UITextField object]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8659f60
2013-01-04 22:54:32.916 ExpenseAccountTracking[39423:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField object]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8659f60'
*** First throw call stack:
...
```

replacing "NumberPadViewController" for "UIViewController" in class "eatAddViewController" work perfectly!

Any clue?

**I have try adding "UITextFieldDelegate" to "NumberPadViewController" without any luck!**

Here the eatAddViewController.m code:

```
#import "eatAddViewController.h"
#import "DateTimeInputView.h"
#import "PickerInputView .h"

@implementation eatAddViewController
@synthesize textAmount, textTips, textTotalAmount, formatter;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.numberStyle = kCFNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;

    DateTimeInputView *dateEntryView = [[DateTimeInputView alloc] init];
    self.textDateTime.inputView = dateEntryView;

    PickerInputView *expenseTypeView = [[PickerInputView alloc] init];
    expenseTypeView.pickerViewOptions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"ExpenseBreakfast", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"ExpenseLunch", nil),
                                         NSLocalizedString(@"ExpenseDiner", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"ExpenseHotel", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"ExpenseOthers",nil), nil];
    self.textExpenseType.inputView = expenseTypeView;
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Add", nil);

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.textDateTime)
    {
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: can you put your code what you had written in eatAddViewController.m

Comment: <UITextFieldDelegate> should be in its view controller.

Comment: Try adding `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in `NumberPadViewController` class.

Comment: Have you searched for the use of the `object` method call shown in the error?

Comment: Code added **Manohar**. Adding only `<UITextFieldDelegate>` to the view controller `NumberPadViewController` give same result **Hercules and ACB**. Adding `<UITextFieldDelegate>` to both `NumberPadViewController` and `eatAddViewController` do not work neither. **Rmaddy**, don't know how to do that!

Comment: Use the Breakpoint Navigator in Xcode to set a breakpoint on Objective-C exceptions.  Your program should stop at the point where you get the error.  You can then type 'bt' in the debugger console and it will print the stack trace, which should at least show where the problem is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **Phillip**. I'm new at Xcode (3 days ;-) and wasn't familiar with this. The problem was in some code I snipped from web (`NumberPadViewController`).

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(NSNotification *)note {
//    [self updateKeyboardButtonFor:[note object]];
    [self updateKeyboardButtonFor:[self findFirstResponderTextField]];
}
```

Without the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` this function was not called. So the problem was hidden before.